# Preventing exceptions from terminating Python iterator

Tags: python

How do you prevent exceptions from prematurely terminating a Python generator/iterator?

For example, consider the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

def MyIter():
    yield 1
    yield 2
    yield 3
    raise Exception, 'blarg!'
    yield 4 # this never happens

my_iter = MyIter()
while 1:
    try:
        value = my_iter.next()
        print 'value:',value
    except StopIteration:
        break
    except Exception, e:
        print 'An error occurred: %s' % (e,)
```

I would expect the output:

```
value: 1
value: 2
value: 3
An error occurred: blarg!
value: 4
```

However, after the exception, the iterator terminates and value 4 is never yielded even though I've handled the exception and haven't broken my loop. Why is it behaving this way?

Comment: Should you use `continue`?

Comment: The whole point of exceptions is to prematurely terminate any context they're not `except`d in.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The generator needs to handle the exception within itself; it is terminated if it raises an unhandled exception, just like any other function.

Comment: +1 although I don't like formulation *it terminated if it raises an exception*... It seems inaccurate.

Comment: Missing "unhandled" is what I mean

Answer (score 2):

You need to handle whatever exception might occur in the generator:

```
def MyIter():
    yield 1
    yield 2
    yield 3
    try:
       raise Exception, 'blarg!'
    except Exception:
       pass
    yield 4 # this will happen
```